# Using MPMediaItem with simpleaudioengine

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem, simpleaudioengine

I've been making a project in cocos-2dx, but needed to create a .mm to select music from the iOS library to play in the background.  I got it working by playing the music in the .mm file, but for various reasons, it needs to play in cocos-2dx using SimpleAudioEngine.  I've tried converting the url's absoluteString to an NSString to an id to a const char* to move it back to the cocos-2dx files, but it still didn't run.

This is what it gave me for the absoluteString(ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=456458322781804615)

.cc-

```
-(void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)collection{
if(collection){
    MPMusicPlayerController* appMusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [appMusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
    [appMusicPlayer play];
    MPMusicPlayerController *iPodMusicPlayerController = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
    MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem = [iPodMusicPlayerController nowPlayingItem];

    NSURL *url = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSString *filePath= [url absoluteString];
    NSString *filePath2 = [url path];
    _songUrl = filePath;
 }
 -(id)returnsongUrl{
     return _songUrl;
 }
```

Second .mm

```
 const char* MediaPicker::songUrl(){
     id na1 = [[MediaPickerWrapper sharedIntance] returnsongUrl];
    const char *cString =  [na1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    return  cString;
 }
```

Cocos-2dx file

```
  CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->preloadBackgroundMusic(media->songUrl());
  CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic(media->songUrl(),false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It filters down to calling AVAudioPlayer's `initWithContentsOfURL:` method and should work with iPod media item urls. However, AVAudioPlayer only gained support for iPod URLs in iOS6. You may need to set a breakpoint to make sure your iPod URL path is getting passed through to the `CDAudioManager's load` method correctly.

You'll have to write your own wrapper and use AVPlayer or AVQueuePlayer if you want to target pre-iOS6 devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011812-SW1